# Enter UTF-32 string in UTF-8 table

Tags: sql, utf

I'm creating a web in ASP.NET (C#), and the tables of my database are UTF-8.
Also I've a register form with fields as "username"

Can a person enter a UTF-32 string in the username field and cause an error? How solve the problem? These UTF-32 characters has more than 0 characters (stringLenght bypassed).

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the whole chain that the data passes. what input do you have, how are the characters transported, which encoding has your api and so on....

UTF-32 is just another "presenation" of UTF-8 for more details i strongly recomment joel spolsky post on that [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: ASP.NET and my web work with UTF-8. Anyway, an user can enter no UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Actually UTF-32 and UTF-8 are both *encodings* for Unicode code points. Whatever the user enters in the website *will* be interpreted according to the encoding settings of that website and the code handling the input. If there is an encoding mismatch, the code hopefully catches that...